# Select Names of city starting and ending with vowels from STATION table

Tags: mysql, sql

Query the list of CITY names from STATION which have vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, and u) as both their first and last characters. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

I tried to run this query but it is returning an empty output

```
/*
Enter your query here.
*/
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiou]%[aeiou]';
```

Comment: see if reading this helps: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: I don't want to use regex, like can be used to handle

Comment: OK, If like can do it, why are you asking how to do it using like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LIKE` pattern you are using is an extension only supported by SQL Server (and Sybase).  In MySQL, you can use regular expressions:

```
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

Comment: He said: "I don't want to use regex".... an now he accepts an answer that uses regular expressions?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'; It worked on MSSQL server, i was trying to run it on mysql server

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
select distinct city 
from station 
where city rlike '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select distinct city from station where city regexp '^[AEIOU].*[AEIOU]$';
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below query works in MS SQL SERVER-

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE LEFT(CITY,1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
AND RIGHT(CITY,1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
```

Comment: Bad solution, not sargable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE LOWER(LEFT(CITY, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') 
      AND LOWER(RIGHT(CITY, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

select DISTINCT CITY from STATION where CITY like 'E%e' OR CITY like 'I%i' OR CITY like 'U%u' OR CITY like 'A%a' OR CITY like 'O%o' OR CITY like 'A%e' OR CITY like 'A%i' OR CITY like 'A%o' OR CITY like 'A%u' OR CITY like 'E%a' OR CITY like 'E%i' OR CITY like 'E%o' OR CITY like 'E%u' OR CITY like 'I%a' OR CITY like 'I%e' OR CITY like 'I%i' OR CITY like 'I%o' OR CITY like 'I%u' OR CITY like 'O%a' OR CITY like 'O%e' OR CITY like 'O%i' OR CITY like 'O%u' OR CITY like 'U%a' OR CITY like 'U%e' OR CITY like 'U%i' OR CITY like 'U%o';

QUITE LENGTHY BUT YOU WILL GET THE QUERY RIGHT

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).